# Creating A Custom Page in SAP Hybris

Tags: components, sap-commerce-cloud, slot

I am trying to create a unique page.
In general, i create a page template , from that template i create a page(in this case it is content page)
then i create content slot with a component within it and create a content slot name for its position at template or page,
afterwards i relate this slot with template or page.

But this time i am working on a different scenario,
What i am trying to do is making the management of this page much more easier.
The customer will create a bundle promotion page on backoffice but creating process contains too much steps on different locations.
I want to gather all these parameters to the page's administration panel.
For example content page's panel have some attributes but i am using my own component's attributes to fill the content slot.

Content Page Type's attributes : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BihSI.jpg .

I want to make a custom cms page type which will appear after pressing the plus sign,
for example Bundle Promotion Page (similar to content page).

creating page menu : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjkKl.jpg .

selecting page type : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD1DL.jpg .

It must have a default template, content slot name, content slot with custom component in it.
All these parameters should be manageable from Bundle Promotion Page's administration panel.
Is this kind of concept possible with Hybris Backoffice?

Comment: which version of hybris you are using now?

Comment: I am using version 6.4

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
please check this [option in latest Hybris](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWLgP.jpg) under WCMS menu in backoffice.There are default page types like email,document etc available as acceleratorservice extension. Custom page types can be created by including any custom attributes and content types.

Comment: Thanks, i am still trying to finist the task. I created a page in core-items.xml and added several attributes. After ant all BundlePageModel had generated along with getters and setters for attributes. This page has a template jsp, problem is i can't access these custom attributes which i added to itemtype. I am trying to create a Controller for this page, minimal functions are OK. But i can't add those parameters to model, i want to showcase them on jsp with ${calledAtrribute}. Any help?

Comment: so you are able to load corresponding JSP,else first you need to specify the page template for the respective page(either through backoffice or using impex import).in the jsp page you need to declare external variable in comment annotation to use.you can refer ProductPageController,its getViewForPage(model),corresponding productdetailpage.jsp of electronicstore.